# CyberSource card number encryption (RSA-OAEP-256)

Tags: typescript, react-native, rsa, cybersource

Is there anyone know here how do I encrypt card number in cybersource?

I tried to encrypt mine using online RSAOAEP encryption tool but I got this response:

```
{
    "responseStatus": {
        "status": 400,
        "reason": "DECRYPTION_ERROR",
        "message": "Cannot decrypt PAN (RsaOaep256): data hash wrong",
        "correlationId": null,
        "details": [],
        "_embedded": {}
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": null,
        "documentation": [],
        "next": []
    }
}
```

Their documentation seems not enough for newbie like me.

Comment: There's an SDK on NPM if that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to get Flex API to work. But whay kind of SDK have you been using? I've implemented it with `React Native v0.61.5` with `Typescript` and with multiple cryptographic libraries: [react-native-crypto](https://github.com/tradle/react-native-crypto), [isomorphic-webcrypto](https://github.com/kevlened/isomorphic-webcrypto), [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js), [js-base64](https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64) and [buffer](https://github.com/feross/buffer). But basically this could be done on any Javascript framework.

I suppose you have `/Keys` request working and i guess you have specified the `encryptionType` to `RsaOaep256`.

Next step is to import the JSON web key (JWK) you received from previous step and encrypt the card number with imported key.

#### Import the JWK

```
import webcrypto from "isomorphic-webcrypto"

const importKey = async (jsonWebKey: any) => {
  return webcrypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    {
      ...jsonWebKey,
      alg: "RSA-OAEP-256",
      ext: true,
    },
    {
      name: "RSA-OAEP",
      hash: "SHA-256",
    },
    false,
    ["encrypt"],
  )
}
```

#### Encrypting the card number

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer"
import webcrypto from "isomorphic-webcrypto"
import { Base64 } from "js-base64"

const encryptCardNumber = async (cardNumber: string, jsonWebKey: any): Promise<T> = {
  const cardNumberBuffer = Buffer.from(cardNumber)

  const publicKey = await importKey(jsonWebKey, "encrypt")

  const encryptedCardNumberBuffer = await webcrypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
      name: "RSA-OAEP",
      hash: "SHA-256",
    },
    publicKey,
    cardNumberBuffer
  )

  return Base64.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(encryptedCardNumberBuffer)))
}
```

Result from this function can be dirrectly passed as `cardNumber` in body of a request under `cardInfo`.

After this, you'll receive `token`, `signature`, `signedFields` and some other fields. You should verify received values against the signature to ensure the values have not been tampered with.

#### Verifying the signature

This one is pretty simple, we'll just need the public key from `/Keys` request that we can find under `der/publicKey`.

```
import crypto from "react-native-crypto"

const verifySignature = (publicKey: string, signature: string, signedFields: string, data: any): booelan => {
  const dataToVerify = data.signedFields.split(",").map(field => data[field]).join(",")
  const verificationKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${publicKey}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

  return crypto.createVerify("RSA-SHA512").update(dataToVerify).verify(verificationKey, signature, "base64")
},
```

I hope this will help you or others having trouble with implementing the Flex API of CyberSource because that has taken toll on me...

Comment: This helped me SOOOOOO MUCH! Thanks. One small change I had to make is in the call `webcrypto.subtle.encrypt(...)` . It seems the "hash" setting is no longer required.

Comment: you rock! logged i for first time in years just to upvote this

Comment: Thanks @IkeemWilson, glad that i could help!

Comment: Thanks @AndrewTempleton, i appreciate it!